# How to add a loader to http interceptor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am working on a ReactJS project which is heavily depending on some APIs.

I have a HTTP service which all the components use for calling APIs.

I need to add a loader such that, it will be shown when some HTTP request is processing.

Currently I am using redux states to open and close the loader. As I cannot change redux states from a service, I am currently calling the loader on/off from components when ever I use http calls.

What I need to achieve is on/off the loader from the service itself so I don't have to think about it whenever I use HTTP service.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

if u want the whole page loader so u can manage its look like. U can directly show hide loader from your HTTP call method.

HttpRequests.js

```
   'use strict';

   function isLoaderManage() {
     let x = document.getElementById("loader");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
         x.style.display = "block";
       } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
       }
    }

    const request = {
        get: (url) => {
            return fetch(url)
                .then((resp) => {
                    isLoaderManage();
                    return resp.json();
                })
                .then((resp) => {
                    isLoaderManage();
                    return resp;
                }).catch((err) => {
                    isLoaderManage();
                    return err;
                });
        },
    }

    export { request };
```

API.js

```
'use strict';

import { request } from './HttpRequests';

const API = {
    getSongs: (URL) => request.get(URL),
}

export { API };
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

index.css

```
#loader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#loader::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.8s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 0.8s linear infinite;
}
```